# How to use a parameter for varchar length in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pass varchar length as a variable. 
What would be the best way to do it?
Following does not work.

```
declare @interval as int = 121;
declare @length as int = 10;

select convert(varchar(@length), bc.date_created, @interval) Datum
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use? It looks to me you want to format date so better use `SELECT FORMAT(bc.date_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` instead of converting with culture and slicing string **[demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414769)**

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2014

Comment: So using answer which you accepted is not probably the best solution. You can easily make format as variable [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414780). But as always it depends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE
      @interval INT = 121
    , @length INT = 10;

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), GETDATE(), @interval), @length)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.